# Downloading image with JS and storing it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following which is grabbing a page full of images:

`headshots = document.querySelectorAll(".jsx-3743397412.player-headshot");`

I am then grabbing the .src of the image with the following:

`shots[i] = headshots[i].firstElementChild.src;`

When I reference shots[i] now, I get a complete link. Unfortunately, using chrome notifications, you cannot use a web link for `iconURL`:

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('', {
    type: 'notification',
    options: {
      title: players[i].innerText,
      message: previousScores[i] + " -> " + scores[i+1].innerText,
      iconUrl: shots[i],
      type: 'basic'
    }
  });
```

What would be the best way to go through a loop of my `shots` array and save each image. Should I be using chrome storage, or just save to my /images/ directory somehow?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: See examples of downloading to a `data URI`, which you can save in storage and use in the notifications API. If the images may be big, see examples of resizing via `Canvas`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions — I will look at those